# How can I do an automatic login to a website with AngularJs Forms in Powershell?

Tags: angularjs, powershell, invoke-webrequest

I'm trying to write a script in `powershell` which will login automatically to a website built with `AngularJS` and store the login session in a variable for future login sessions.Can someone please tell/show me how to go about solving the problem? Thanks a million in Advance.

I've done it before and it always works successfully, only in this case the website was build with `angularJs` and the form has `InputFields` hidden in 'Div' tags. So doesn't work.

This is how the form looks:

```
<form name="loginForm" class="login-form gf-form-group ng-pristine ng-invalid 
       ng-invalid-required" ng-hide="disableLoginForm">
    <!---->
  <div class="gf-form" ng-if="loginMode">
     <span class="gf-form-label width-7">User</span> 
     <input type="text" name="username" class="gf-form-input max-width-14 ng- 
       pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" 
       required="" ng-model="formModel.user" placeholder="email or username">
   </div> 
     <!---->
     <!---->
   <div class="gf-form" ng-if="loginMode">
     <span class="gf-form-label width-7">Password</span> 
     <input type="password" name="password" class="gf-form-input max-width-14 
         ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" 
         required="" ng-model="formModel.password" id="inputPassword" 
         placeholder="password">
   </div>
     <!---->
     <!---->
   <div class="gf-form-button-row">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large 
      p-x-3 btn-inverse" ng-click="submit();" ng-class="{'btn-inverse': 
      !loginForm.$valid, 'btn-primary': loginForm.$valid}">Log in</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

This is the script I wrote (which I usually use):

```
$LoginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://mywebsite/login' -SessionVariable 'sVar'

$Body = @{loginForm = $LoginResponse.ParsedHtml.forms[0].elements['loginForm'].value
    username = 'MyUsername'
    password = 'MyPassword'
}

$LoginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://mywebsite/login' -WebSession $Session -Body $Body -Method 'POST'
```

This is the error I get when I run the script in `Powershell`:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:3 char:1
+ $Body = @{
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Invoke-WebRequest : [{"fieldNames":["User"],"classification":"RequiredError","message":"Required"}]
At line:10 char:18
+ ... nResponse = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://mywebsite/login' -WebSessi ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: Looks like perhaps `ParsedHtml.forms` was a zero-element array?

Comment: @RossPresser, thanks for answering, but no it isn't. Moreover I don't think that's the problem because the script works perfectly with other Forms (of Not Restful api)